# List initialization of a reference: is GCC or Clang correct?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, list-initialization

Given this example:

```
int g_i = 10;
struct S {
    operator int&(){ return g_i; }
};

int main() {
    S s;
    int& iref1 = s; // implicit conversion

    int& iref2 = {s}; // clang++ error, g++ compiles fine:
                      // `s` is converted
                      // to a temporary int and binds with
                      // lvalue reference

    int&& iref3 = {s}; // clang++ compiles, g++ error:
                       // cannot bind rvalue reference
                       // to lvalue
}
```

The errors are as described in the comments.
**gcc 8.2.1** and **clang 7.0.1** were used and disagree about what is happening in this example. Could someone clarify this?

[In list initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#list) :

> Otherwise, **if the initializer list has a single element** of type E and either T is not a reference type or **its referenced type is reference-related to E**, the object or **reference is initialized from that element** (by copy-initialization for copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for direct-list-initialization); if a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert the element to T, the program is ill-formed.
>
> **Otherwise, if T is a reference type, a prvalue of the type referenced by T is generated.** The prvalue initializes its result object by copy-list-initialization or direct-list-initialization, depending on the kind of initialization for the reference. The prvalue is then used to direct-initialize the reference. [ Note: As usual, the binding will fail and the program is ill-formed if the reference type is an lvalue reference to a non-const type. — end note ]

[In reference initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#ref):

> Given types “cv1 T1” and “cv2 T2”, **“cv1 T1” is reference-related to “cv2 T2” if T1 is the same type as T2, or T1 is a base class of T2**. “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2” if
>   - T1 is reference-related to T2, or
>   - T2 is “noexcept function” and T1 is “function”, where the function types are otherwise the same,

...[and later on there's some (personally ambiguous) language on user-defined conversions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#ref-5):

For example:

> If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>   ...
>   **has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), where T1 is not reference-related to T2, and can be converted to an lvalue of type “cv3 T3”, where “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv3 T3” (this conversion is selected** by enumerating the applicable conversion functions ([over.match.ref]) and choosing the best one through overload resolution),
>   ...
>   then the reference is bound to the ... value result of the conversion

...

> Otherwise, if the initializer expression
>   ...
>   has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), where T1 is not reference-related to T2, and can be converted to an rvalue or function lvalue of type “cv3 T3”, where “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv3 T3”
>   ...
>   then the value of the ... result of the conversion in the second case is called the converted initializer. If the converted initializer is a prvalue, its type T4 is adjusted to type “cv1 T4”

...

> Otherwise:
>   - If T1 or T2 is a class type and T1 is not reference-related to T2, **user-defined conversions are considered using the rules for copy-initialization of an object of type “cv1 T1” by user-defined conversion** ... The result of the call to the conversion function, as described for the non-reference copy-initialization, is then used to direct-initialize the reference. **For this direct-initialization, user-defined conversions are not considered**.

...

> Otherwise, **the initializer expression is implicitly converted to a prvalue of type “cv1 T1”**. The temporary materialization conversion is applied and the reference is bound to the result.

These rules are quite nuanced and I cannot fully grasp each situation.
To me, it seems like a prvalue should be getting generated (I agree with clang), but the language on reference initialization, and interaction with list initialization is very fuzzy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's read the standard in the correct order, so that we know which sections apply to the situation at hand.

[dcl.init]/17 says:

> The semantics of initializers are as follows... If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list* or is `=` *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is list-initialized (11.6.4) ...

So we go to [dcl.init.list] (11.6.4). Paragraph 3 says:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows: (... cases that don't apply are elided from this quotation...) Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type `E` and either `T` is not a reference type or its referenced type is reference-related to `E` ... otherwise, if `T` is a reference type, a prvalue of the type referenced by `T` is generated. The prvalue
>   initializes its result object by copy-list-initialization or direct-list-initialization, depending on the kind of initialization for the reference. The prvalue is then used to direct-initialize the reference. [ *Note:* As
>   usual, the binding will fail and the program is ill-formed if the reference type is an lvalue reference to a
>   non-const type. *—end note* ]

According to [dcl.init.ref]/4:

> Given types “*cv1* `T1`” and “*cv2* `T2`”, “*cv1* `T1`” is *reference-related* to “*cv2* `T2`” if `T1` is the same type as `T2`, or `T1` is a base class of `T2`.

Therefore, in your code, the referenced type `int` is not reference-related to the type in the initializer list, namely `S`. Thus, by [dcl.init.list]/3, a prvalue of type `int` is generated, and it takes the form `int{s}`. And as the note says, in the case of `iref2`, the program is ill-formed because it tries to bind a non-const lvalue reference to a prvalue. In the case of `iref3`, the program should compile since `iref3` is being bound to the prvalue result `int{s}`.